# Suddenly "turning on" of friction

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction

In David Morin's textbook on classical mechanics, he states the following for a situation where we have a rope on an inclined plane, pinned with a nail at the top end-

> Another special case occurs when the rope is placed on a frictionless plane, and then
> the coefficient of friction is “turned on” to µ. The friction force is still zero. Changing
> the plane from ice to sandpaper (somehow without moving the rope) doesn’t suddenly
> cause there to be a friction force.

It seems quite intuitive that friction shouldn't change immediately. But can I predict how will friction change with time- I mean can I predict linearly, exponentially, so on, or arbitrarily, considering this is quite an idealistic and hypothetical case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems quite intuitive that friction shouldn't change immediately.
> But can I predict how will friction change with time-

Morin is not talking about how long it will take for friction to be "turned on". He is saying *there will not be a friction force at all* if the ice is replaced by sandpaper, no matter how much time passes.

The reason is a friction force parallel to a surface can only exist in opposition to another net force parallel to the surface. In the example, the force on the rope down the plane of ice is balanced by the reaction force of the pin acting up the plane, for a net force of zero. Clearly, no friction is needed to prevent the rope from sliding down the plane as long as it is pinned. Replacing the ice with sandpaper doesn't "turn on" a friction force.

On the other hand, if the pin is suddenly removed while the rope is on the sandpaper, a friction force will appear in opposition to the otherwise unopposed force of $mg\sin\theta$ acting down the plane. Whether or not the friction force is static friction or kinetic friction will depend on whether or not the maximum possible static friction force of $mg\cos\theta$ is exceeded.

This is probably easier to understand if you consider a block on a horizontal surface. If there is no net net external force applied horizontally to the block, the block will remain stationary without the need for a friction force. It doesn't matter if the block is on ice or sandpaper. Likewise, if two equal and opposite external parallel forces act on the block, there will be no friction force acting on the block, whether it is on ice or sandpaper.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ohh, yes i completely overlooked this idea. Thanks!